How to implement 'Step-up' authenticate using AAD B2C
We use B2C with email/phone MFA. I want to protect risky/sensitive actions by asking users to re-authenticate using a TOTP.
I can see examples of this pattern in other services, but not B2C. I looked though B2C docs and Googled.
Does B2C support this flow? How could I support this flow using B2C?
https://www.descope.com/learn/post/step-up-authentication
https://auth0.com/docs/secure/multi-factor-authentication/step-up-authentication/configure-step-up-authentication-for-apis

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone . One of the Starter Packs has a simpler example that shows the basics of implementing MFA
